# Повышая версию ретрофита он перестает работать. В чем проблема?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

Я загружаю через ретрофит одну картинку, когда в зависимостях прописываю старые версии, картинку грузится, но при использовании последней версии нет. Также проверял на новом проекте, новые версии скачивают картинку, значит как мне кажется проблема в самом проекте, но переписывать его не хочется, подскажите в чем проблема.

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface Service {
    @GET("703/377045-blackangel.jpg")
    fun getURL() : Call<ResponseBody>
}

object XXX {

    private val base_url = "https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/"

    val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)).build()
    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(base_url)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api :Service by lazy {
        retrofit.create(Service::class.java)
    }
}
```

Во фрагменте пишу это

```
val call = XXX.api.getURL()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val byte = response.body()!!.bytes()
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte, 0, byte.size)
                    binding.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {

            }
        })
```

Мои зависимости когда успешно

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

и ответ приходит такой

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/703/377045-blackangel.jpg http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 4411 (msec)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/le.harrypotter: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/703/377045-blackangel.jpg (896ms)
D/OkHttp: Server: nginx/1.16.1
D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 16 Jul 2022 14:58:48 GMT
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: image/jpeg
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 326133
D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
D/OkHttp: Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jan 2017 22:39:12 GMT
D/OkHttp: Expires: Sat, 13 Jan 2018 22:39:12 GMT
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
D/OkHttp: Accept-Ranges: bytes
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (binary 326133-byte body omitted)
```

а когда неуспешно

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.2'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

и ответ такой

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/703/377045-blackangel.jpg http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 1020 (msec)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200  https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/703/377045-blackangel.jpg (756ms)
D/OkHttp: server: nginx/1.16.1
D/OkHttp: date: Sat, 16 Jul 2022 14:57:44 GMT
D/OkHttp: content-type: image/jpeg
D/OkHttp: content-length: 326133
D/OkHttp: last-modified: Fri, 13 Jan 2017 22:39:12 GMT
D/OkHttp: expires: Sat, 13 Jan 2018 22:39:12 GMT
D/OkHttp: cache-control: max-age=31536000
D/OkHttp: accept-ranges: bytes
```

Comment: почему метод `onFailure` пустой? может там приходит ошибка? залоггируйте `Log.e("tag", "error", throwable);` или распечатайте ошибку: `throwable.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Как вариант, не перескакивайте сразу 2.3 -> 2.9, а по одной минорной версии подымайте и как сломается читайте тут что поменялось. https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md